# PHP MySQL INSERT INTO parsing error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I have a funny assignment of moving Joomla 1.0 content to Joomla 3.2 content. I wrote a few scripts for categories, worked fine. Now I am working on porting script for articles and I keep getting an error in this MySQL query:

```
$qr = "INSERT INTO nlqov_content 

(id, asset_id, title, alias, introtext, fulltext, state, catid,
 created, created_by, created_by_alias, modified, modified_by,
 checked_out, checked_out_time, publish_up, publish_down, images,
 urls, attribs, version, ordering, metakey, metadesc, access,
 hits, metadata, featured, language, xreference
) 

VALUES 

(7,125,'Welcome to Joomla!','welcome-to-joomla','', '', 0, 61, '2004-06-12 11:54:06', 
62, 'Web Master', '2004-06-12 12:33:27',62,0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '2004-01-01 00:00:00', 
'0000-00-00 00:00:00', '{"image_intro":""}', '{"urla":false}','{"show_title":""}', 
 1, 1, '', '', 1, 10, '{"robots":"","author":"","rights":"","xreference":""}', 0, '*', '' )
```

Which errors with:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'fulltext, state, catid, created, cr' at line 1 - error_num: 1064

I can't find out what is wrong with that query. I checked data types, they are fine.

I ommited some JSON data for code to be clearer.

I'll be glad if anybody can help. This may very well be an error of tired eyes, so sorry for that :)

Comment: [**FULLTEXT is a Mysql Reserved Keyword**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) add bacticks around it

Comment: Wow 3 upvotes? Because the OP is ignorant about the keywords?

Comment: @asprin sometimes stackoverflow behaves like so dramatically strange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fulltext` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. Either use backticks to escape it or use another name.

```
INSERT INTO nlqov_content (..., `fulltext`, ...
```

Comment: I thank you, that worked :) Oh, those Joomla developers ... :)

Answer (score 1):

fulltext is mysql keyword use back tits like this

```
$qr = "INSERT INTO nlqov_content 

(`id`, `asset_id`, `title`,`alias`, `introtext`, `fulltext`,....)
```